# CakePHP 3.5.5: can loading a model cause infinite recursion?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Something in my code is causing certain calls to `TableRegistry::get()` to cause what looks like infinite recursion.

When I request the table Jobs it works fine. For the table Currencies (and others) I get this error:

> Fatal error of  Maximum function nesting level of '256' in /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/functions.php on line 92.

Here's the stack trace:

```
1. {main}() bin/cake.php:0
2. Cake\Console\CommandRunner->run() bin/cake.php:12
3. App\Shell\IngestionShell->initialize() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Console/CommandRunner.php:140
4. Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get() src/Shell/IngestionShell.php:32
5. Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->get() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/TableRegistry.php:132
6. Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->_create() cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:216
7. Cake\ORM\Table->__construct() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:249
8. App\Model\Table\CurrenciesTable->initialize() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:291
9. Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get() src/Model/Table/CurrenciesTable.php:14
10. Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->get() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/TableRegistry.php:132
11. Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator->_create() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:216
Cake\ORM\Table->__construct() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Locator/TableLocator.php:249
13. App\Model\Table\CurrenciesTable->initialize() vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php:291
...
```

After that it just repeats endlessly until the fatal error.

I'm calling this in `initialize()` before anything really has happened:

```
class IngestionShell extends Shell
{   
    private $currencies;
    private $jobs;

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        // This works:
        $this->jobs = TableRegistry::get('Jobs');
        // This crashes:
        $this->currencies = TableRegistry::get('Currencies');
    }
...
}
```

**Similarly** when I run `$this->loadModel('Currencies');` in a controller I run out of memory, this time in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Utility/Inflector.php` on line 597.

```
class PagesController extends AppController
{
    public function home() {
        $this->loadModel('Currencies');
    }
...
}
```

I don't have any relations between models explicitly set up - e.g. `hasMany()` - and the table structure is super simple. Here are the two relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  symbol varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  is_primary tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  is_deleted tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE jobs (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  job_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  job_time int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  options json DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE currencies
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY symbol (symbol),
  ADD KEY is_primary (is_primary);

ALTER TABLE jobs
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);


ALTER TABLE currencies
  MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE jobs
  MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

EDIT: including the CurrenciesTable class. Could the call to `TableRegistry` in `initialize()` cause the recursion?

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
class CurrenciesTable extends Table
{
    public $currencies;

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->currencies = TableRegistry::get('Currencies');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please show more of the stacktrace, including one recursion. And since the problem seems to be possibly located/triggered in the `CurrenciesTable` class, please show the code of that class too. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: @ndm - Thanks for the pointers, I've added this info now. I'm thinking the call to TableRegistry in initialize must have something to do with it. I thought this would only result in two calls, but why would this result in recursion?

Comment: That surely is the source of the problem, yes. It will not result in only two calls because `Table::initialize()` is being invoked at constructor time, and the check in the table locator that prevents multiple instantiation is only effective once the the first instance has been constructed completely. That being said, there's no reason to make this call in the first place.

Comment: I'm cleaning out those lines and yes that seems to have been the snag. I don't understand 100% why but it makes sense. Slightly off topic if you would indulge me - what's the correct way of calling find() etc from within e.g. CurrenciesTable? The reason I stored the table in a class variable was because it was handier than calling TableRegistry::get() inside class methods.

Comment: You'd call it like any other member method, ie via `$this`... `$this->find()`

Comment: That is what I thought, and my first try. Coming back to Cake after a long break. I got an error suggesting the table object didn't have that method, which is why I ended up with this workaround, but I'm sure something else was wrong then. Glad to get my first hunch confirmed, will try again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A call to `TableRegistry::get()` in the model's `initalize()` function was causing the recursion. The reason for this call, as it turns out, was probably a misunderstanding of how the model works and, as npm points out in his comment, shouldn't need to be there.